# Is it possible to persist chrome extensions' hidden state between sessions?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

This has been an annoyance for years. Every time Chrome relaunches all of my hidden extensions are visible. It makes no sense why it wouldn't remember that.

For anyone with the same problem here's a time saving tip I found; you don't need to right click hide each extension. Instead, move your cursor in between the address bar and drag the divider to the right. You can shrink the extension area's space, hiding as many of the right-most extensions as you need in one move.

System Info: Windows 10 Home, Chrome version 75.0.3770.100 (and every version for the last several years).

Comment: Obviously that is a bug. Your question is hard to answer though … what version of Chrome? What OS? Have you tried with a new profile?

Comment: @slhck It's Windows 10 and every version of chrome for years. By profile do you mean signing in to chrome with a different account?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you could add a new person (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and see if the problem persists there. Are you currently synchronizing your settings with your Google account?